# Alternatives to bottled water in the UK

Tags: water, plastic, alternatives, uk

I live in Devon, and tap water in my household does not taste consistently. When I moved in my current property, the neighbours warned me that they had been buying bottled water since 20 years, because of the bad taste and other suspects about the quality of the water.

Thus, for the first time in my life, last year I started buying water bottled in plastic, and have done so until now.

I wonder if there is any valid alternative that does not require the application of a permanent filter (I am a tenant). Back in Sicily, where I grew up, we used to go to a spring in the mountains once a month, to refill our glass and plastic bottles. In other countries, water refill stations exist. Is there anything of the sort in the South West of England?

Comment: What about a faucet-mount water filter, like this -- http://amzn.eu/4xCEJeI? I am a renter and have used these in the past. As long as your faucet has a screw-mount aerator these work.

Answer (score 2):

From a BBC article on 2018-01-25:

> [**Plastic bottles: Free water refill points rolled out to cut waste**](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-42808302)
>
> **Shops, cafes and businesses will offer free water refill points in every major city and town in England by 2021.**
>
> Industry body Water UK says its scheme could cut disposable plastic bottle use by tens of millions a year.
>
> The move comes amid growing concern about the effect of plastic waste on the environment.
>
> Whitbread, which owns Costa Coffee and Premier Inn, is the first to sign up to the initiative and will provide water in all of its branches from March 2018.
>
> Refill stations and public fountains will be able to be found via an app or window signs pointing people in the direction of the nearest one.
>
> ...

More details are available in the [Water UK press release](https://www.water.org.uk/news-water-uk/latest-news/new-national-drinking-water-scheme-water-companies-cut-plastic-bottle-use).

[Refill.org.uk](https://www.refill.org.uk/) is where you can go to download the app and find refill stations.

Refill stations exist in [Devon itself](https://www.recycledevon.org/RefillDevon).

Comment: Great initiative! We have something similar in [The Netherlands](https://www.krnwtr.nl). I guess all the OP now has to do is figure out which nearby cities provide higher quality tap water. Perhaps [this post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18836/is-tap-water-in-ireland-and-england-drinkable) or [this article](https://www.water.org.uk/consumers/water-and-health/faqs#Trust?) can help with that.

Comment: Added a link to refill.org.uk to the answer — it lists the refill areas and makes the app available for download that locates specific refill points.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at the website of South West Water, the company that supplies tap water for Devon, and they have a page on [Tastes and smells](https://www.southwestwater.co.uk/water-advice-and-services/drinking-water-services/drinking-water-quality/tastes-and-smells/) where they say that

> ...often unusual tastes or odours relate to issues with private plumbing or appliances in your home.

And they provide a list of possible problems and solutions.
So perhaps you can check if it's only a problem in your building. If so you could try talking to your landlord.

However, the website also says that

> It’s normal to notice a slight taste or smell of chlorine in your water as we add a small, safe amount to protect it from harmful bacteria.

so perhaps the bad taste is more widespread and comes from the added chlorine. In that case you could go to an area that is served by a different drinking water company that doesn't add as much chlorine, and fill up big canisters there.

Answer (score 2):

There are jugs with filters.  This happens to be a Brita.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have  the same problem and for months bought glass bottled water which was way to expensive and not really the ideal either! Recently I bought a decent filter even though it was a bit costly, I am sure it purifies my water , and I can take it anywhere with me if I move house !